# Orientation(geometry)

Tags: geometry, rotations

A **xy**-plane is rotated about **x** and **y**-axis. But when it is rotated along **z**-axis, it doesn't change the orientation of **xy**-plane, why?

I've tried to find the answer but those answer that i found didn't have main reason.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you mean... Do you think to $\pi/2$ or $\pi$ rotations ?

Comment: full 2π rotation

Comment: I am still confused in "xy-plane is $2\pi$ rotated about x and y-axis" : do your "and" means "then" ?

Comment: In 3d coordinates system. When xy-plane is rotated about x-axis, Is it also rotated about y-axis automatically? I was trying to visualize it in my mind....

Comment: Is there a connection with [Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) ?

Comment: you can consider that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation around an "axis" is an illusion brought on by the fact that we live in three dimensions. Rotation is really around 2D planes.
In 2D, there is one plane: the space itself. So rotation is more of a back and forth.
In 3D, every 2D plane corresponds to a perpendicular direction and vice versa. This direction is the "axis".
When you rotate around the z-axis, you're really rotating around the xy-plane. The xy-plane itself is naturally invariant under this rotation.

In higher dimensions, you can rotate around more than one plane simultaneously.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see what your answer is for.

Comment: He asked why when the xy-plane is rotated along the z-axis, its orientation doesn't change. I'm saying that because rotating along the z-axis is actually rotating along the xy-plane, the xy-plane won't move.